# Grupos de rotas com valores padrão no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-rotas

Preciso entender como crio rotas com valores padrão (seria o `default` que temos na função `switch` do PHP). Procuro algo do tipo:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/'], ['as' => 'public'], function(){

    Route::get('/{userid}', function () {
        return 'Perfil publico do usuário';
    });

    //rota de exemplo do que estou procurando, esta seria a default
    //caso o usuario não tenha buscado nenhum outro usuario no site
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return 'Página inicial do site'
    });

});
```

Qual o melhor método para gerar esse tipo de rota? há alguma função default para grupos de rotas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente colocar uma interrogação (?) ao final de `{userid}`.

Assim sendo, você define o valor padrão para a variável do parâmetro, que representa o id passado na url.

```
Route::get('/{userid?}', function ($userid = null) {
     if ($userId === null) {
         //Lógica para acesso feito apenas com a '/'
     } else {
         Usuario:findOrFail($userId);
         ...
    }
});
```

Então, teríamos dois acessos à mesma rota:

```
meu.site/
```

e

```
meu.site/1
```

Comment: Excelente! não pensei que podia fazer condicionais dentro de um mesmo get rsrs obrigado!

Comment: Acho que dá pra fazer da sua forma. Porém, você teria que declarar a rota `/` antes do `/{userid}`. Falo por experiência da "precedência" da declaração das rotas no Laravel 4 :)

Comment: Sim Wallace, eu acabei batendo em outra tecla, porque eu fazendo dessa forma fica funcional dentro dos controllers, ex: se eu quero um formulário de cadastro, se meu usuário enviar um id (edição) eu faço algo, se não (novo usuário) ;D